# Menuitems appear in wrong place on scaled monitor Issue

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I'm working on a JavaFX Application and came across an issue. When I run my program on a 150% scaled Windows monitor the Menu items appear in the wrong place.

[image: JavaFX Menu scaling]

Can I fix this in code or is this a known issue with JavaFX on scaled monitors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

This behaviour was caused by my secondary monitor which has a different resolution than my laptop screen. 
As soon as I disconnected my secondary monitor the problem was gone.